# Associate software engineer

Tags: system-analysis

I will work as a  associate software engineer in a company, but so far I do not know what are the responsibilities required from me .

and I do not know what is the difference between a software engineer,systems analyst and programmer

so can anyone help me in this subject ?

Comment: This is very much dependent on where you work and what your supervisor expects. Most of those titles are just that: titles. They don't necessarily indicate or imply a specific job task. It was cool for a while to call programmers "software engineers". "Software wizard" was even all the rage for a while. Most of the time, they're just different names for the same job. But your company might assign specific meaning to them; it's best to ask them to find out.

Comment: I don't think anyone that is not familiar with your company can help you with this

Comment: I am curious how did you decide to apply for this job and why did you decide to take the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this question is best answered by your supervisor at work?

Comment: I agree... But I think this would be better suited as a comment, rather than as an answer.